# Spring Roo to use slave database for read-only operation (or transaction)

Tags: mysql, database, spring, jdbc, spring-roo

Our project would like to have master-slave Database configuration.
And we would like to do write operation in master database, while read-only operation in slave database.

We noticed this article having the sample JDBC connection source code that can help: 
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/connector-j-reference-replication-connection.html

However, as our project is heavily reliant in Roo persistence models. How can we set such configuration in Spring Roo?

Thanks,
Robert